# Is appuse 2.2.1 possible to use a smtp server which need authentication?

Tags: authentication, smtp, appfuse

I have specified the smtp server and authentication info in the mail.properties, but appfuse 2.2 just ignores the mail.username and mail.password properties.
How to workarround this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out.
The smtp setting is located in appfuse-service-2.2.1.jar/applicationContext-service.xml.
Copy it to src/resources, rename it to applicationContext-services.xml, and uncomment the authentication settings, modify the mail.properties to add auth info.

Modify the web.xml, change the contextConfigLocation, use the new applicationContext-services.xml.